# SQL Query to Group Shop Visits?

Tags: soql, query

I am trying to group the number of times a subscriber has visited each unique store but am getting an error:

```
select subscriberkey, storename, count (orderID) as shopvisits from salesorder 
   group by subscriberkey,storename
```

What is missing from/incorrect about this query?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SOQL doesn't support 'as' keyword in aliasing. You can alias a table like

```
select o.subscriberykey, o.storname, o.orderid from salesorder o;
```

Also you should use **Aggregate Functions** in your case. Aggregate functions in SOQL, such as AVG(), SUM() and MAX(), allow you to roll up and summarize your data in a query.

```
AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT AVG(Amount)aver FROM Salesorder];
Object avgAmount = groupedResults[0].get('aver');
```

> Note that any query that includes an aggregate function returns its
>   results in an array of AggregateResult objects. AggregateResult is a
>   read-only sObject and is only used for query results.

An example of Aggregate Function with a Group By clause. This is not the exact solution you are looking for as I don't know your data model. This is just for representation of an aggregate function which returns AggregateResult

```
AggregateResult result:[SELECT status__c status, Count(Id) Sum, 
                               subscriber__c subscriber 
                          FROM Salesorder 
                         WHERE status__c IN ('Fulfilled', 'Received') 
                      GROUP BY status__c, subscriber__C];
```

Comment: How would I write that for this:

SELECT subscriberkey, Count(orderid) shopvisits, 
                               storename
                          FROM Salesorder 
                      GROUP BY subscriberkey, storename

When I check syntax I get a notification indicating that Select must be the first word of the query.

@bennie

Comment: Did you paste the query in with a bunch of leading spaces? Remove them if so.